# Deserializing Pokemon API in .NET

Tags: c#, json, rest, json.net, deserialization

I'm attempting to deserialize the pokemon API located at https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3 and I'm relatively new to working with json. I've made a class and method that loads whatever pokemon I choose into an object but can only get it to work with the simple keys like "name: value" and "id: value"

```
 class Pokemon
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

      //  [JsonProperty("abilities")]
      //  public Dictionary<string, string>[] Abilities { get; set; }

        //[JsonProperty("types")]
        // public Dictionary<string, int>[] Types { get; set; }

        //[JsonProperty("sprites")]
        //public Dictionary<string, string> Sprites { get; set; }

        public static Pokemon LoadPokemon(int num)
        {  
            string json = new WebClient().DownloadString($"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{num}");
            Pokemon pokemon = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Pokemon>(json);
            return pokemon;
        }
    }
```

All of the fields I can't make work I've commented out. Basically my question is how do I make those fields I've commented out actually load. I've tried a combination of dictionaries, arrays, and lists as datatypes but I can't seem to make anything work.

```
 "sprites": {
    "back_default": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/back/3.png",
    "back_female": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/back/female/3.png",
    "back_shiny": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/back/shiny/3.png",
    "back_shiny_female": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/back/shiny/female/3.png",
    "front_default": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/3.png",
    "front_female": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/female/3.png",
    "front_shiny": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/shiny/3.png",
    "front_shiny_female": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/shiny/female/3.png",
    "other": {
      "dream_world": {
        "front_default": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/dream-world/3.svg",
        "front_female": null
      },
      "official-artwork": {
        "front_default": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/official-artwork/3.png"
      }
    },
```

'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'sprites.other', line 1, position 189387.' This is my usual error message when I attempt to load sprites, and the other attributes have similar errors. I can see why the "other:" key wouldn't work with Dict<string, string> but I also don't know how to avoid that problem since not every key in sprites has that format.

Also I'm using NewtonSoft.Json and System.Net packages. You can find the abbreviated version of the API at https://pokeapi.co/.

Comment: Please do not add unrelated tags (i.e. `[ASP.NET]`).

Comment: Please also include a short JSON sample in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to figure out the correct C# structure for very complex JSON documents can  be quite difficult.  I would suggest you start by using one of the many online JSON to C# convertor tools (e.g. https://app.quicktype.io/ or Google "JSON to C#") to take a sample JSON document and generate your class models.  Using the sample JSON from https://pokeapi.co/, I used the quicktype tool to instantly generate the C# models.  You can then take that C# code and modify it to suit your needs (create separate files for each class, remove unneeded properties, etc).  But at least this provides you with a good (and valid) starting point.  Tools like quicktype have config options that allow you to to refine the models, such as if you want JSON arrays to be C# arrays or Lists, etc.

Answer (score 0):

"sprites" in your example will resolve to a `Dictionary<string, object>`. You will then, in your code, have to cast the value to either `string`, or another `Dictionary<string, object>` in the case of "dream_world" and "official_artwork".